# Optimizing pagination of HTML tables

Tags: javascript, php, html, layout, pagination

I'd like to share my implementation to you to confirm if it's a correct way to solve my problem. I have a list of products which have an attributes table and a description table (both in html_encoded strings). Every product starts at a new print-page using page break. When the attributes and description tables don't fit in one page I want to print the description in the next page.

My solution is to print the attributes table and then print the description div twice: once in the same page with the attributes and once at the next page using a page break; After the page has loaded using JavaScript, I measure the height of both attributes+description and if that is higher than 800 pixels (which means that two pages will be needed) I hide the first description. If their height is lower than 800 pixels (which means they can fit in the same page) I hide the second one.

(I know for certain that neither of the two tables will exceed one page by itself)

Is this a solid solution or are there possible cases in which it will lead to a big mess?

```
<script>
    function measure(){
        $total_count=document.getElementById("total_product_count").value;
        for(var i = 1; i <= $total_count; i++){
            $description_id='description['+i+']';
            $second_description_id='description['+i+']_second';
            $attributes_id='attributes['+i+']'; 
            $combined_height = document.getElementById($description_id).clientHeight + document.getElementById($attributes_id).clientHeight;

            if($combined_height>800){
                document.getElementById($description_id).style.display = 'none';
            }
            else{
                 document.getElementById($second_description_id).style.display = 'none';
            }

        } 
    }
</script

<body onload="measure()">
.
.
.
<input id="total_product_count" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $total_product_count; ?>" />

<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
    <div>...small image + title....<div/>
    <div  class="attribute" id="attributes[<?php echo $product['product_count']; ?>]" ><?php echo $product['attributes']; ?></div>
    <br/>
    <!--show the first description in the same page as attributes -->
    <div id="description[<?php echo $product['product_count']; ?>]" class="tab-content"> <?php echo $product['description']; ?></div> 
    <div id="second_description[<?php echo $product['product_count']; ?>]" class="tab-content">
           <!-- show the second description at the next page --> 
          <p style="page-break-after: always; text-align: center;"></p> 
          <?php echo $product['description']; ?>
    </div> 
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an actual solution to your problem, but I noticed that you aren't using `var` to declare your JavaScript variables. Doing so automatically declares them in the global scope, which is a bad idea as a general rule of thumb and can quickly lead to unpredictable behavior. Declaring variables should be done like `var myvar = myvalue`:

```
<script>
    function measure(){
        var $total_count=document.getElementById("total_product_count").value;
        for(var i = 1; i <= $total_count; i++){
            var $description_id='description['+i+']';
            var $second_description_id='description['+i+']_second';
            var $attributes_id='attributes['+i+']'; 
            $combined_height = document.getElementById($description_id).clientHeight + document.getElementById($attributes_id).clientHeight;

            if($combined_height>800){
                document.getElementById($description_id).style.display = 'none';
            }
            else{
                 document.getElementById($second_description_id).style.display = 'none';
            }

        } 
    }
</script>

...
```